# google-analytics: Conversions not showing on Transactions

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have installed Google tag manager and the following tag is firing and being count accordingly for my E-commerce conversion (tag called 'Google Analytics eCommerce'):

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-76425812-2', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': inspectionID
  });

  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': inspectionID,
    'name': 'Inspection',
    'quantity': 1
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Nevertheless I am trying to create a tag and to avoid firing multiple tags for the same conversion. For that, I am creating a universal tag to save the utm_source and I am storing it on a Custom Javascript Variable.

TAG:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href;
var keyToFind = 'utm_source';
if(url.indexOf(keyToFind + '=') > -1)
{
var valueFound = url.substr(url.indexOf(keyToFind + '=') + keyToFind.length + 1).split('&')[0];
sessionStorage.setItem(keyToFind, valueFound);      
}
</script>
```

Java Script Variable:

```
    function()
{
return sessionStorage.getItem('utm_source');
}
```

When I use this variable to trigger any other tag (this is not triggering the Google Analytics eCommerce tag at all), GA stops considering the conversions.

Anyone may have an idea about what can be happening in the case?

Thanks,

Helton